# Using angular cli for component libraries

Tags: angular, angular-cli

We are building Angular 2 apps in a large enterprise and many times we share code via NPM packages built as Component libraries. I was hoping to stay consistent and use the same tooling for both the SPA and the libraries. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: There are some major changes coming in both Angular and the CLI.
The new `@AppModule` structure will make it more consistent and clear, it's a perfect match for angular 2 3rd party libraries, infect all angular2 packages use that, for example the Router will have a RouterModule, so does Forms and others...

In the CLI they are now migrating to Webpack as the underlaying build tool and ditch Broccoli, which was somewhat complex to understand.

These 2 major changes will make it easier to adopt the angular-cli for both SPA and libraries.

Comment: @ShlomiAssaf Does this mean we are required to use Webpack in our angular apps once these changes are released? I currently have two teams standardizing this CLI and it sounds like we should wait. Our apps are enterprise grade and I do not want to have to make a lot of changes to them when these CLI changes are pushed out. This is concerning to me to say the least.

Comment: We are dealing with a bleeding edge, non final framework that has a lot (really a lot) of `@experimental` API's. You should expect change, this is inevitable. If you're on RC4 (I hope you are) you will notice it when moving to RC5... if you don't was to use deprecated api's that will be gone on final.

The CLI itself is a tool that tries to abstract the technology, so the fact that the CLI use's webpack shouldn't make any difference if you use the CLI in all projects. That's the goal of this tool. You are not required to use webpack, the CLI use it... you might not even know about it

Comment: In other words, the CLI commands will not change, the process for developers will not change.

BTW, Moving to Webpack was a matter of time, the current CLI is based on SystemJS which is a very non friendly environment. It's also not a bundling tool which forced using other things for bundling which is a big headache.

My assumption is that on moving to a webpack based CLI some changes will be mandatory to a CLI based project but it will be limited to specific areas like index.html structure etc... I don't thing the application itself will need modification

Comment: @ShlomiAssaf Thanks for your input. It's important for us to standardize library development as well so I will stick with the CLI.